# HttpWebRequest timeout (being blocked) c#

Tags: timeout, httpwebrequest, fiddlercore, pcap.net, sharppcap

I have a c# application that downloads multiple tiny files from websites (torrents). Some sites restrict the number of downloads per IP per day.

I do a HttpWebRequest and if the stream is a valid torrent, I save it to disk.

Is there a way for my c# application to spoof my IP when performing the HttpWebRequest, so that the download will not fail ?

I spaced out the download time to one per 10 minutes, but no luck. I still get blocked eventually.

I have heard that "TOR" can use diffrent IPs, but I don't want the people using my desktop app to have to install TOR browser separately.

```
           HttpWebResponse resp = null;

        try
        {
            var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.exampe.com/test.torrent);
            req.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip,deflate");
            req.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip;
            req.Timeout = 30000;
            req.KeepAlive = true;
            resp = (HttpWebResponse)(req.GetResponse());

        }
```

Any solutions ?

Answer (score 1):

To do so, you need to manipulate tcp/ip packets. This means that you need to capture the outgoing packet created by HttpWebRequest and change its source IP to the spoofed one.

I found this forum post that seemingly has to do with what you want to do, check it out : http://pcapdotnet.codeplex.com/discussions/349978

As far as I know you can do it through [PCap.net](http://pcapdotnet.codeplex.com/) or [SharpPcap](https://github.com/chmorgan/sharppcap) libraries.

Comment: Wouldn't doing so prevent the response packets from getting back to you? Besides, you'd have to change your public ip address which may not be the ip address of your system.

Comment: That's right and the Spoofed IP should be in your subnet to be routed back to your network. And if you're behind a NAT server, I think it wouldn't be possible. You can spoof but as NAT changes the packets again it would be pointless.